# ASP.Net Core API: where to insert code to generate GUID

Tags: c#, events, click, crud, addition

I am using the CRUD methodology to allow the user to add a new record to an existing database from Razor Page input values.
I have created a button which, when clicked, should generate a GUID as primary key for the newly-created record.
My only remaining hurdle is to figure out where the click event(C# code) must be inserted within the project to generate the GUID.
Where must this code be in order to be executable upon button-click?

Comment: Why don't you want to leave that functionality for your database? For example, Postgres has built-in function `uuid_generate_v4()` for this purpose. It automatically generates new Guid. What database are you using?